# Javascript this.value onchange not working

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I'm trying to get the value of a form input usign JS:

HTML:

```
<td onchange="validate_hours(this)">{{ form.monday }}</td>
```

JS:

```
function validate_hours(elem) {
   console.log(elem.value)
}
```

But I receive "undefined".

The {{ form.monday }} is a Django form

Django form:

```
<input type="number" name="form-0-monday" value="4.0" step="any" placeholder="0.0" id="id_form-0-monday">
```

Comment: But if I remove the ".value" I get the inner HTML, including the changed value (value="5.0")

Comment: Are you trying to fire an event when the corresponding *form* updates? Because Javascript doesn't know a thing about whatever templating engine is filling in that `{{ ... }}` syntax

Comment: Yes, thats correct, that {{ form.monday }} is a Django form, therefore, a number type input, I want to get the number that is input within the form everytime it is changed

Comment: `td` elements don't have a value property. I'm surprised that onchange is firing somehow tbh. Seems like this should be an `<input . . .`. This question should include the generated html or be tagged with django probably.

Comment: @CarlosS.C. You should add an answer, not put the answer in your question.

Comment: @CollinD `change` event bubbles up, that's why it can be captured also on `td`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I used firstChild to get the input and now is returning the value:

JS

```
function validate_hours(elem) {
  input = elem.firstChild.value
  console.log(input)
}
```